# Is Python 2 removed from 14.04 CD images?

Tags: python, release-management, 14.04

I haven't seen an update on the status of removing Python 2 from the CD images, and [this page](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Python/3) has last been updated late 2013.

Comment: I presume is the server images that you noticed this change, since the Desktop has still python 2.

Comment: Nope, I didn't know. I was asking from complete ignorance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No Python2.7 is still there for desktop, check the CD manifest [here](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/daily-live/current/trusty-desktop-amd64.manifest):

```
python2.7   2.7.6-8
```

But has been removed from the server image ([manifest](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-server/daily/current/trusty-server-amd64.manifest)) as explained in the [migration plan](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Python/FoundationsTPythonVersions) where desktop is the last target.

Comment: @Tshepang: I've updated my answer to include the server image

Answer (score 9):

### For 14.04: server and desktop images

The situation is:

- there is no python2 on [the server image](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-server/daily/current/trusty-server-amd64.manifest)
- but python2 is part of the [the desktop image](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/daily-live/current/trusty-desktop-amd64.manifest)

### The logic

I quote:

> It is **a release goal for Ubuntu 14.04 (Trusty Tahr) that we ship only Python 3 on the touch, server, and desktop images.** Don't worry, Python 2.7 will still be available in the archive, and more specifically 'main' for now.

Python 2 is removed from the **server** images, you are absolutely right! For the server, don't worry python2 is still in the repos and can thus easily be installed.

Now the migration to python3 is not completely finished for the desktop (which involves more python packages than the server). The desktop image thus still has python2.

Source: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Python/FoundationsTPythonVersions

Comment: Now that your answer has been edited I can revert my vote. There's still an image (desktop) that provides python2.7.

Comment: @SylvainPineau Read the edits. My edit changed the order of the answer, not the content.

Comment: You removed "Python 2 is removed from the images, you are absolutely right!". That's all I wanted to see for removing the downvote. Thanks

Comment: @SylvainPineau Point taken.

Answer (score -1):

According to [packages.ubuntu.com](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=python&searchon=names&suite=trusty&section=all) Python 2.7.5 is the default version.

Comment: How can you tell that it's default from that page?

Comment: It says "(default version)" where others have the repository the package is located in.

Comment: Oh, I see. I missed that. It does not necessarily mean it gets to be part of the image.